# aws sql UNNEST an array of varchar

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, unnest

A table    `var` with a column     `variationscsv`contains an array of elelments
["el","el2","3el"..] in each row.
How to UNNEST the column to check if "el56" is in a row ?
desired output will contain the original     `variationscsv`    column and  a boolean column with the result of the test:      `True` if "el56" is in the array and     `false` otherwise.
Will apretiate your help.

Tried

```
    WITH vars AS (
    SELECT 
    vars.variationcsv
        AS items
         )
    SELECT i AS array_items FROM vars
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(items) AS t(i)
    WHERE contains(i, 'el56')
```

received an error

```
Column 'vars.variationcsv' cannot be resolved
```

Comment: I would guess the error is caused by your table being called `var` but you are looking for `vars.variationcsv`.  You can't access the alias until it has been created by the subquery returning something

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten the `FROM var` statement in your subquery, no?

You may also have an issue with the naming of your columns in the main query.